# How can I change my iterative code to a recursive one?

Tags: c, recursion

```
int findnumb(int max)
{
  int left,right,total,desk;
  for(total=2; total<=max; total++)
  {
    for(desk=1; desk<total; desk++)
    {
      left=desk*(desk-1)/2;
      right=(total*(total+1)/2)-(desk*(desk+1)/2);
      if(left==right)
      {
        printf("Desk number %d, number of participants %d\n", desk, total);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I turn this into a recursive function?

It works well in this form, but when I try to change it to a recursive function it compiles, but doesn't work properly, what should I do?

**Edit:**

It is for a riddle like this:

Suppose that there exists a meeting and we do not know how many people attend to it. 
However, we see a man quitting from the meeting. If we ask the man how many people 
exist at the meeting he just replies “I do not know”. Nonetheless he says “I was sitting on 
a chair numbered x and summation of the numbers below and above me equals. In other 
words, if the number of the chair is x, then 1,2,3….x-1 = x+1 x+2 …...t-1,t (total 
participant count). Besides, we do not know the value of t and the chair number x. 
Total participant 8, and the chair number 6 is an example configuration. Because 
1+2+3+4+5 = 7+8 = 15. Your task is to find similar configurations by one by one try-out.

And It wants the solution to implement a recursive function

**Second Edit:**

Now I have produced a code that finds the numbers and crashes right after that why is it happening?

Here is the screenshot of the code and the crash https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzYrk.jpg

Comment: Why don't you describe the purpose of your code?

Comment: Also, why do you want it done recursively? If either way is an option, the iterative is generally the better one.

Comment: Post your attempts of making it a recursive function, and a description of the trouble-shooting you have done so far.

Comment: Please don't just link screenshots of text! You should add the salient parts to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables that need to change in each iteration need to be argumants and you need to be true to the functional approach so instead of printing you should return the result:

```c
int findnumb_aux(int max, int total, int desk)
{  
    if( total > max ) {
         return 0; // need to return something when no solution exist
    } elseif( desk < total ) {
         int left=desk*(desk-1)/2;
         int right=(total*(total+1)/2)-(desk*(desk+1)/2);
         if(left==right) {
             return desk<<8+total;  // there are better ways to return two numbers. you figure it out
         } else {
             return findnum_aux(max, total, desk+1);
         }
    } else {
        return findnum_aux(max,total+1, 1);
    }
}

int findnum(int max)
{
    return findnum_aux(max, 2, 1);
}
```

Fun fact: This code is still iterative since it does not grow the stack *if* your C compiler has [tail call optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and before reading your answer I was trying a code, It successfully finds the numbers but crashes right after that, here is the screenshots of this: [link](http://imgur.com/a/UgZgC) Why is this happening ?

Comment: @Kaupp Perhaps it's because not all of your exits return an int. My answer return with the very first answer. To get all answers you need to accumulate answers on the way and return them in place of `return 0`.

Comment: I think I get it, thanks again for the answers !